# Github actions workflow 'on' and conditions

Tags: github-actions

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
    paths:
      - 'dataloaders/xxx/**'
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['CI']
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  xxx_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
```

I want to achieve something like this: so above workflow only get run when both the two conditions: `path 'dataloaders/xxx/**' got changes` and `CI workflow successfully completed` are met, **now seems it is `or(||)` between this two conditions, thus: the path filter is ignored!**

How can i make the conditions be `and(&&)`?

Comment: you're gonna have to manually add conditions to your job if you want this (`if: ...`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve what you want using those `on` trigger alone.

This happens because those triggers work separately (according to one **OR** the other condition).

In that case, a workaround is to use only one condition at the `on` trigger level, then check the other condition inside the workflow / jobs steps, using an `if` condition.

For example, at the place you use the condition `if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}`, you could add another check using `if: [...] && [variable telling me if the path I want has been updated]`

**However, in your particular scenario, checking a path has been updated after another workflow run conclusion isn't easy.**

My suggestion would be, instead of triggering your new workflow like this, to trigger this workflow by a [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) or a [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event, calling this workflow in a separate job at the end of the previous workflow (the one called `CI`), where this job would only be executed if all other jobs from the `CI` workflow would be executed successfully, and if the path you want has been updated (for example, using a [path-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) action to check the path and decide if you should call or not your new workflow).